# SQL - can't get to DB after canceling query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

i tried to insert table from too big flat file. after few hours when it didnt finished (and eat all my drive space) i cancel the query (which also take long time).

since then i cant reach all that DB tables. when i tring to expand tables' folder from object explorer window, i get error message :

> (ERROR 1222) Lock request time out period exceeded. (.Net SqlClient
>   Data Provider).

i also tried restore this DB from backup

> Restore of database 'WorkTablesDB' failed.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Exclusive access could not be obtained
>   because the database is in use. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

any option how to get this DB to work again?

Comment: Try running `DBCC OPENTRAN` on that database (and possibly on tempdb as well). You very likely have open transactions from the data insert failure that failed to close gracefully. `KILL` any open transactions, and that should clear up your database.

Comment: already tried.. "No active open transactions."

Comment: EDIT: i close the ssms and open it again and it work!!! tnx

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to close SSMS. it will prompt you to either close any open transaction or not.
Choose yes to commit all open transactions and lunch it again. it will run